# Create Column in MySql on Insert

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have devoted a long time of my career on MySQL and recently shifted to MongoDB. On of the very fine feature about MongoDB is that we don't need to alter or create columns on Collection/Table specifically. The column will be created as we insert Data. For e.g., If we have a collection/table named as Emp in MongoDb, I can pass an object to it like:

```
{
   id:12,
   name:'abc',
   phone:8298999
}
```

If Emp doesn't has column phone or any other, it will not report an error, rather the missing column will be created automatically on insert, and previous records will hold a default null value for newly created column.
Does such functionality exists in MySQL? To summarize, while Inserting a new record in MySQL table, if a column doesn't exists in table and is mentioned in INSERT query, can that missing column be automatically created with a default value?

Comment: No, You have to define the tables and columns before storage in MySQL.

Comment: To add in, mysql is a schema based DBMS and subsequently requires that template (definiton of column & its data type) for storage. Mongodb is essentially schema-less.